# Unable to capture Jmeter Variable at a particular Position using Regex

Tags: regex, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Below is my sample Response Data

```
</tr>
    <td>Auth Status:</td><td>A</td>
</tr>
```

Below is Regular expression I am using, which return more than 1 occurrences.

```
Expression :<td>Auth Status:<\/td><td>[A-Z]<\/td>
Template : $1$
Match No. : -1
Default Value : Use Empty Default value
```

I am trying to call using index no. as ${AuthStatus_1} which returns null value. Although when calling ${Authstatus_MatchNr} returns the count of 4.
Not sure what am I missing here. Requesting for some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is missing one essential part: [capture match group](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html), surround your `[A-Z]` with parentheses and it will start working as you expect:

[image]

More information:

- [JMeter Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)